# XMLHttpRequest status 0 but responseText correct

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have the following HTML file, *test.html*:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

From the console, on a separate file in the same directory, I enter

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "test.html", true);
request.send(null);
```

Now, `request.responseText` contains the contents of the HTML file, but `request.status` and `request.statusText` are 0 and "" respectively. I've seen a hundred questions with the `responseText` being empty and the status 0, but I can't find anything with the `responseText` acting correctly and the `statusText` not. Why might this be happening? Any ideas?

Comment: Ajax in "Async" requires `onreadystatechange`.

Comment: I'm entering all of these one at a time on the console. By the time I enter console.log(request.status) request.readyState is already 4.

Comment: But just in case, I tried it with an onreadystatechange function; status still returns 0.

Comment: What was the situation with the `http://` you had? Please be clear.

Comment: The issue was probably with the protocol. I'm setting up Apache, and I'll tell you once I'm able to try it. Thanks.

Comment: You use PHP, .NET, Java (jsp or jsf) or something? I've edited my answer. No offense, but honestly you need the basics before you start in WEB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Learn the basics

Before you START programming for Web you should understand what is [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [WebServer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server), [Client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client_%28computing%29), [Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), [Response](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request-response) and [Status Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

### Protocol file vs http

Protocol `file://` don't work with `XMLHttpRequest` by browser security, prefer `http://`.
For use `http://` in your PC/Machine install [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) or [Nginx](http://nginx.org)

### You use PHP, .NET, Java (jsp or jsf) or something?

To start working with "WEB" is advisable to know a programming language and perhaps a framework:

- Django (Python FrameWork) install [Django 1.6.2](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/)
- [Django+Windows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/windows/)
- PHP+Windows install [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- PHP+Linux (or Windows) install [Xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html)
- ASP.NET (asp.net is a framework, you can programing in [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c#) or [VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vb.net)) install [Microsoft ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/downloads)
- JSF2 (Java is language and Facelets is "template"): http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/01/jsf-20-tutorial-with-eclipse-and.html
- Rails (Ruby is language and Rails is "Framework"): http://rubyonrails.org/

### Ajax vs Sjax

Ajax in Async-mode requires `onreadystatechange`

Ajax (["A"synchronous Javascript and XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "test.html", true);//true is "async"

request.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
    if (request.readyState==4) {
        console.log("status: "+request.status);
        console.log("response: "+request.responseText);
    }
};
request.send(null);
```

"SJAX" ("S"ynchronous Javascript and XML):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "test.html", false);//false is "sync"
request.send(null);
if (request.readyState==4) {
    console.log("status: "+request.status);
    console.log("response: "+request.responseText);
}
```

Prefer asynchronous mode, so that you can work multiple events without a need to wait for the other and also avoid freezing the "javascript".

Comment: You were right; the issue was with using `file://` instead of `http://`. I know Python. Is that enough to get by in the beginning, or do you suggest learning PHP or Ruby before proceeding too far? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Python is pretty good too! Try Django framework. I edit my answer.